# Sometimes right-clicking on magic mouse does not work

Tags: mouse

I'm using Mac and magic mouse.

Left-clicking on the mouse always works. But sometimes, when I right click on the magic mouse, it just does not work. So I have to right click again or again and again.

It was not very very harmful, but now I'm making videos and recording screens, everything needs to be perfect. So I'm wondering why sometimes my right-clicking does not work. Is it the way I right-click wrong?

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem too. You are not right-clicking on the correct position on your mouse. You should play with it and make a note or put a mark on your mouse to show where on the mouse you need to press to get a right-click. I found placing your finger on the right side of the mouse near the edge and towards to top works best for me.